# How to do the Comparison of Two Functions

Tags: sml

I would like to know how to compare two function `F(x)` & `G(x)` in SML, which two functions must return the same value that `f(x)==g(x)`, where `1<= x <= 100`.
For example:

```
- fun f x = x*x;    
val f = fn : int -> int
- fun g x = x+x;
val g = fn : int -> int
- iden f g;
val it = false : bool
- fun f x = x*x;
val f = fn : int -> int
- fun g x = if x<0 then 0 else x*x;
val g = fn : int -> int
- iden f g;
val it = true : bool
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking about? Are you asking for the implementation of `iden` or? Granted this is the case, what have you come up with yourself?

Comment: the function "iden" can check whether f(x) and g(x) have the same value where 1<= x <= 100
for example :
fun iden f g = if f(2)=g(2) then true else false;
but how can i test all the cases for x from 1 to 100?

Comment: Well you could create a recursive function that tests f(i) = g(i), for i = 1, and then for i+1, i+2, i+3... Just as you have described yourself

Comment: I have got another way to do so by creating a list which map the function g and f to it , and then compare two list . Anyway,thanks for your answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Since testing whether or not two functions (programs) are equal for all inputs is not computable, your `iden` function will likely have to take more parameters than just the two functions that its comparing.

In general, your `iden` will be:

```
- fun iden f g elem = f(elem) = g(elem)
val iden = fn : ('a -> ''b) -> ('a -> ''b) -> 'a -> bool
```

In your specific case, you would probably want to do something like this:

```
- fun iden f g = let
=   fun iden_h f g (a, b) =
=     if a > b then iden_h f g (b, a)
=     else if a = b then f(a) = g(a)
=     else f(a) = g(a) andalso iden_h f g (a+1, b)
=  in
=   iden_h f g (1, 100)
=  end
val iden = fn : (int -> ''a) -> (int -> ''a) -> bool
-
- iden (fn x => x + x) (fn x => 2 * x);
val it = true : bool
- iden (fn x => x + x) (fn x => x * x);
val it = false : bool
```